# Distinguishing between head node and other nodes in a derived type procedure

Tags: linked-list, fortran

Am working on a module that looks a little like this:

```
module linked_elems

type link
  integer :: i
  double precision :: a
  type(link), pointer :: parent=>null()
  type(link), pointer :: child=>null()
contains
  procedure forward_op
  ! and all the usual linked list stuff
end type

type(link), target :: head

contains

subroutine forward_op(ln)

class(link), target :: ln

! do stuff to ln%i and ln%a

! if ln == head do extra stuff to ln%i and ln%a

!Operands of comparison operator '==' at (1) are CLASS(link)/TYPE(link)V
!if (ln == head) then  
!  print *,'ln is head'
!endif

!Error: ‘pointer’ argument of ‘associated’ intrinsic at (1) must be a POINTER
!if (associated(ln, head)) then  
!  print *, 'ln is head'
!endif

end subroutine

end module
```

The real module is much more involved, but this illustrates the problem I am having.  In `subroutine forward_op()`, the head node of the linked list needs to be treated a little differently than any of the other nodes.  I am having trouble figuring out how the subroutine can tell whether it is dealing with the head node.  In the code I have put in the two approaches I have tried, along with the compilation errors they give.

I can distinguish the head node by the fact that if the code is executed properly, it will be the only node whose parent element is unassociated.  But maybe someone is going to come along later and try to put the code to use in, for instance, a way that needs a circular linked list, and then the parent criterion won't work.  In any event, it seems to me preferable to find some way to detect the head node based simply on its own existence in memory, apart from the values of any of its elements.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need `class(link)` to be target and not pointer? If it was `type()`, you should still be able to make a pointer to `link`: `link_p => link` and do the associated check `associated(link_p, head)`. But the whole design with one single fixed head looks strange. You can probably always take `cptr`s, convert them to integers and compare those...

Comment: @VladimirF   Making class(link) a pointer is a complete no-go.  Regardless of whether I do any comparisons at all, the compiler tells me that the argument to that routine cannot be a pointer.

Comment: Either the subroutine needs to be told it's dealing with the head node or to figure it out for itself.  You could achieve the former by adding a logical field (perhaps called `is_head`) to the node.  If that doesn't float your boat and you want to go with the subroutine figuring things out for itself, perhaps have the head node point to itself as its own `parent`.

Comment: The head bode can be identified by having null parent (or maybe by being parent of itself). The null parent approach is the more reasonable, for me. It also makes obvious if a branch is removed from a tree, is becomes the root of a new tree and vice versa